# Java Stream mapping and groupingby field that no longer exists after map

Tags: java, collections, stream, java-stream, groupingby

I'm gonna give a little example of what i need. I have this simple beans:

```
public class Item {
   
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private Category category;
   
   //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

public class SimpleItem {
   
    private String name;
    private String code;
   
   //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

I need to map and group a `Collection<Item>` to a `Map<Category,List<SimpleItem>>`. I tried something like this

```
public class itemMapper {

    public Map<Category,List<SimpleItem>> map(Collection<Item> items){
        return items.stream()
                    .map(this::mapToSimpleItem)
                    .collect(groupingBy(Item::getCategory));
    }
    
    private SimpleItem mapToSimpleItem(Item item){
        //
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that after the mapping, the field category no longer exists. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using `.map(this::mapToSimpleItem)` so in the collect part you have a `Stream<SimpleItem>` and not `Stream<Item>`

Comment: OP knows that, OP is asking how to group and then map basically, which the first answer explains.

Answer (score 2):

To get what you want you need to use  `groupingBy` with `mapping` and not `map` before the collect, because as I said in comment, `.map(this::mapToSimpleItem)` return `Stream<SimpleItem>` and not `Stream<Item>`, your code should be:

```
return items.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Item::getCategory, 
                mapping(this::mapToSimpleItem, Collectors.toList())));
```